# Elasticbeanstalk Nginx Reverse Proxy Conf for Different Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am looking to reverse proxy a different server IP from my application when a user goes to `/blog` on my website. I have set up what I believe to be the correct nginx `location` block configuration and successfully deployed an ebextension with the configuration, but when I navigate to `/blog` I receive the 404 page that is rendered from my application's server. On further inspection the request shows that the request was made to the application IP and not the IP address found in the `/blog` location block in my nginx setup. Can anyone help determine what might be wrong with either my ebextension, nginx or application setup that is preventing the nginx location block to work? I'm not sure how to test beyond requesting the url and checking the network resource tab in my develop tools.

**Here is my ebextensions folder setup:**

```
> ebextensions
=> nginx
==> conf.d
==- 01_nginx_blog_rp.config
-00_nginx_https_rw.config
-02_sequelize_db_migration.config
```

**01_nginx_blog_rp.config**:

```
files:
  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/01_blog_proxy.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 10M;

  "/etc/nginx/conf.d/02_blog_location_block.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        server {
            location /blog {
                proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:2368;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            }
        }

container_commands:
  01_reload_nginx:
    command: "sudo service nginx reload"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you trying to achieve is not possible with just adding simple `location` block in `conf.d`.

You basically defining a new `server` block with `location` inside. This new `server` block is never used by nginx because you already have default `server` config generated by ElasticBeanstalk with configured `listen` and `server_name` directives. This two directives are used by nginx to decide where to forward request, therefore all incoming requests going to your application server and ignoring your customizations.

What you really need to do is to **modify** existing `server` block and add your `location` into it.

**This can be done in a few different ways:**

**- Create new nginx config and delete default one.**

In this [aws documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/nodejs-platform-proxy.html) example they just adding a new `.ebextensions/proxy.config` and replace default nginx config with the custom one. Using this approach you can have a full control of your nginx configuration.

**- Create new config and make it processed before default one.**

If you still want to keep default config around you can just keep using your `00_nginx_https_rw.config` name of config, this way nginx will process your config first, and if in your config you will have correct `server_name` and `listen` it will be used by nginx to process incoming request.

**- Add hook to modify default config.**

[On AWS forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=228527) you can find another solution  -  add bash script hook to
modify existing config.

Comment: Thank you for this answer Igor! This has been super helpful and something that I could not find anywhere I searched.